# I need to pass a nonce from `_document` to `_app` in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I tried using the `enhanceApp` or `enhanceComponent` but the prop or static property never reaches `_app` for some reason.

```
  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => {
        App.nonce = nonce;
        return App;
      },
      enhanceComponent: (Component) => {
        Component.nonce = nonce;
        return Component;
      }
    });
```

Or even:

```
  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App: AppType | React.ComponentType<{nonce: string}>) =>
        function EnhancedApp(props) {
          return <App {...props} nonce={nonce} />;
        }
    });
```

> Obs.: I cannot add a `getInitialProps` in app because I need static page optimization.

Is this the right approach? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @juliomalves Nope, it doesn't for some reason... your example also doesn't for me:

I get `>>> nonce in _app 
undefined` in the console on CodeSandbox

Comment: I see what you mean, it's not available during client-side hydration - but it is there on the server-side if you check the dev server terminal.

Comment: If you, like me, need the nonce during the client render I'd look into the following:
- Next.js 12: Implement Next.js middleware
- Next.js 11: Pass the nonce using `getServerSideProps` in (all) your pages